# Can I use Windows Recovery Environment and a Windows 8 DVD image to restore my Samsung Series 9 notebook to OEM condition

Tags: windows-8

What happened so far: I decided to install Ubuntu on my Samsung Series 9 notebook. Here's my current partition table:

[image: (click me!)]
.

As you can see, I kept most of the recovery partitions. I did not change the first three and the last one. Unfortunately, I decided to format the biggest one of the recovery partitions (because I needed the space and thought, that I don't want to reinstall Windows).

I can still start the Windows Recovery Environment from the boot menu. Of course, it's not able to restore Windows because one partition is missing.

However, the Windows Recovery Environment gives me the option to use a system image file to restore Windows (and a few other advanced options). My university provides me with a Windows 8 Installation DVD. Can I use this DVD to restore my notebook to OEM condition? (Samsung support is not being helpful here...)

Comment: The Windows 8 disk you've been given will require a licence key for the version they have given you. The sticker on the back of your laptop will say what version you have but the sticker will most probably have an OEM code which can't be used to activate Windows. The recovery partition you deleted will have a "pre-activated" version of Windows (the OEM version). But you deleted it. I'm afraid that you are going to have to buy the recovery disks...

Comment: If you use the uni disk it may not be the same version pre-installed on your laptop and then you'll need the correct license. But it won't be the same install as the factory one.